# Python script ends before async callback

Tags: python, asynchronous

I am using a library that asynchronously calls a server method like so:

```
def asyncCallback(error, result):
    print error, result

server.call("methodname", [param1, param2], asyncCallback)
```

The only problem is that the asyncCallback never gets called. I thought for a while this was an issue with the API I was using until I added a `exiting = raw_input("about to exit")` which will hang the program up. Then I will see the asyncCallback printout.

Any ideas how to handle this situation? Honestly, it would be so nice if this was just synchronous, e.g. `error, result = server.call("methodname", [param1, param2])`. I suppose that would have major performance shortcomings but this is just a convenient script and the program won't be doing anything else but waiting for the callback in the meantime.

Comment: Is this `server.call` from a public module?  What do you get for documentation if you instantiate server on the python command line and do `help(server)` ?

Comment: What library is it? It's hard to answer this question without knowing how the library is implemented.

Comment: [Its a pretty obscure library](https://github.com/hharnisc/python-meteor) for connecting to [meteor web servers](http://meteor.com) through python.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the main thread of execution wait for some flag that the callback will explicitly set. Here's example using [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) (and [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to allow passing arbitrary arguments to your callback):

```
from threading import Event
from functools import partial

def asyncCallback(event, error, result):
    print error, result
    event.set()

event = Event()
func = partial(asyncCallback, event)
server.call("methodname", [param1, param2], func)
event.wait()  # This will block until asyncCallback calls event.set()
```

Comment: sweet! this looks like it would work, but any ideas how to prevent the code from all looking like spaghetti?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I came up with using @dano's answer as a starting point. I'm basically using a function decorator to wrap an async function so that it acts like a sync function.

```
def syncify(func):
    def wrap(func, *args, **kwargs):
        event = Event()
        results = []

        def async(*args):
            print 'called back'
            print args
            results.append(args)
            event.set()

        print 'calling'
        kwargs['callback'] = async
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        event.wait()

        print 'results'
        return results[0]

    return partial(wrap,func)


print 'wrap it'
print syncify(client.call)('user', ['chet'])
```

And its working great!

But are there any drawbacks to this approach? I'm surprised that this isn't implemented elsewhere...

Comment: That's basically what I was going to suggest. So nothing wrong with it, in my opinion.